# IDisposable object disposed before end of using block

Tags: c#, active-directory, dispose, idisposable

I have a `using` block around an `IDisposable DirectoryEntry` to create the directory entry, access one of its properties, and then dispose of it. However, the directory entry is being disposed prior to the end of the using block.

```
public static PropertyValueCollection GetProperty(
    this Principal principal, string propertyName)
{
    using (var directoryEntry = principal.GetAsDirectoryEntry())
    {
        return directoryEntry.Properties[propertyName];
    }
}

public static DirectoryEntry GetAsDirectoryEntry(
    this Principal principal)
{
    return principal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
}
```

The error is thrown on the `return directoryEntry.Properties[propertyName];` line, saying that the directory entry is already disposed. I can remove the using block and the code will work, but I am concerned that the object is never getting disposed. I call this multiple times, so are multiple instances of the directory entry being created and never disposed?

Comment: Are you sure it is this line? Or could it be the consumer when it uses the `PropertyValueCollection`?

Comment: @YacoubMassad - Indeed (at least from code shown so far) - OP explicitly said that "I call this multiple times" - so I think they know that they dispose result of `.GetUnderlyingObject()` multiple times... complete [MCVE] would help to see error coming on second call to `GetProperty` for the same `principal`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code isn't creating the `DirectoryEntry` instance, nor is the `Principal.GetUnderlyingObject()` method (which isn't a factory method).  Since your code doesn't manage the lifetime of the instance, your code shouldn't be disposing it.

In this particular case, the instance returned by `Principal.GetUnderlyingObject()` is actually stored in state of the `Principal` instance.  After you dispose it once, every subsequent call to `Principal.GetUnderlyingObject()` on the same `Principal` instance will return the same, previously disposed, instance.